# How to change path to the one before the previous directory?

Tags: command-line

Assuming a Vistising sequence using cd:  1. directory C, 2, directory B, 3, directory A.

Now if we usually use **cd -**, it goes back to directory B

if we again use **cd -**, we come back to the directory A.

Is there any way we can go back to directory C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd`.

```
$ pushd ~/test/A
~/test/A ~/test
$ pushd ~/test/B
~/test/B ~/test/A ~/test
$ pushd ~/test/C
~/test/C ~/test/B ~/test/A ~/test
$ popd
~/test/B ~/test/A ~/test
$ popd
~/test/A ~/test
```

These commands maintain a stack of directories so that you can make your way back!

Comment: does this mean that we always need to use **pushd** instead of **cd** to change directories sothat the directory stack are recorded?

Comment: Yes. You could `alias cd='pushd >/dev/null'`